# cannot run commands in tinkerwell over ssh connection (laravel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, tinker

Tinker works just fine when I am ssh'd into my box, but I cannot get it to work in tinkerwell.

I'm trying to connect to my local vagrant box with tinkerwell. It is a vagrant box running in windows: ubuntu 20, laravel 5.7, php7.3.33. Tinkerwell 2.25 in Windows 10. I can connect over ssh, but it errors out whenever I run any command:

[image]

> In Shell.php line 79:
> Argument 1 passed to _PhpScoperc223a629f245\Psy\Shell::add() must be
> an ins     tance of
> _PhpScoperc223a629f245\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command,      instance of Psy\Command\ParseCommand given, called in
> phar:///tmp/vagrant_t
> inker.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php on line 316

I get the same error whenever I try to run any command. On google I found a thread where someone had the same issue, except they were not connecting over ssh, they were on a mac, and the thread had no resolution in it (https://github.com/beyondcode/tinkerwell-community/issues/215).

I have checked that the correct version of php is in my $PATH, so the default path of `php` for the php executable that tinkerwell picks seems correct. I have also tried specifying `/usr/bin/php` but it doesn't change anything.